# Prove that $\Bbb P $ is not a $F_{\delta}$ set by Baire category theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove that $\Bbb P $ (set of irrational numbers) is not a $F_{\delta}$ set by Baire category theorem.

The book I'm reading says to first suppose that $\Bbb P = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n$ such that each $F_n$ is closed in $\Bbb R$.  Then $\Bbb R = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n  \cup \bigcup _{q \in \Bbb Q} \{q\}$ and to use Baire category theorem to prove otherwise.  Since $\Bbb R$ is a complete space and  $\Bbb R = \ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$, there exists an $n$ such that the closure of $X_n$ has a non-empty interior.

What I'm confused about is how to interpret Int(closure($X_n$)) = Int$(closure(F_n \cup \bigcup_{q \in \Bbb Q}\{q\})) \neq \emptyset$.  This would be all of $\Bbb Q$ and its derived set, which make up $\Bbb R$.  Where would the contradiction be?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\Bbb R = \color{red}(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n\color{red})  \cup \color{red}(\bigcup _{q \in \Bbb Q} \{q\}\color{red})$.
As you have argued, one of these closed sets on RHS has nonempty interior. Suppose it is $F_m$. But $F_m\subseteq\mathbb P$, which implies $\mathbb P$ has nonempty interior. This is absurd.

Comment: If $F_m$ has a non-empty interior, then Int$(closure(F_m)) \neq \emptyset$.  But isn't the closure of a subset of $\Bbb P$ a closed set in R?

Comment: And the only closed sets in R that make up $ \Bbb P$ happen to be unions of singleton sets in R.  Therefore there's no interior?

Comment: @Oliver: By hypothesis $F_m$ is already closed in $\Bbb R$, so I don’t see the point of your first question. As for your second question, *all* subsets of $\Bbb R$, closed or not, are unions of singleton sets in $\Bbb R$. Note, by the way, that contrary to what you may have thought, $\Bbb P$ contains closed subsets of $\Bbb R$ whose cardinality is not just infinite, but the same as that of $\Bbb R$ itself. But all of this is beside the point. As **Eclipse Sun** said, if $F_m\subseteq\Bbb P$, so if $F_m$ has non-empty interior, than so has $\Bbb P$. We know that $\operatorname{int}\Bbb P$ ...

Comment: ... *is* empty, however, so we have a contradiction.