# Proof that $\Bbb Q$ is not a $G_{\delta}$ set by Baire catagory theorem corollary.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I start by supposing $Q = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}O_n$.  Then by a corollary to the Baire Category theorem: A complete space that can be written as $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$ has $\ge 1$ n such that Int(closure($X_n$)) $\neq \emptyset $.

Therefore because $R = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}O_n \bigcup \Bbb P $, we can write that $X_n$ = Int(closure$(O_n \bigcup \Bbb P))$.  But aren't the closures of both $O_n$ and $\Bbb P$ $= \Bbb R$, where would the contradiction be?

Comment: $\Bbb P$ is the set of irrationals? Anyway, what makes you think this argument is correct? DId someone tell you it was correct or what?

Comment: Hmm, ironclad proof that that argument simply cannot be correct, or close to correct: The _only_ property of $\Bbb Q$ you use is the assumed fact that it's a $G_\delta$. So if this argument were correct it would show that _no_ set was a $G_\delta$.

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804497/prove-that-bbb-p-is-not-a-f-delta-set-by-baire-category-theorem and probably a lot of other questions from the past.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know quite how to answer the question because I don't see why that argument *should* be correct. Hint for a correct argument:

Suppsoe $\Bbb Q$ is a $G_\delta$. Say $\Bbb Q=\{r_1,r_2,\dots\}$, and let $\Bbb Q_n=\{r_n,r_{n+1},\dots\}$. Each $\Bbb Q_n$ is a dense $G_\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{P}$ is a $G_\delta$, as its complement is countable and hence an $F_\sigma$, e.g. it's the intersection of the sets $D_q := \mathbb{R} \setminus \{q\}, q \in \mathbb{Q}$, which are all open and dense.

If $\mathbb{Q} = \bigcap_n O_n$ where the $O_n$ are also open and dense (as they contain the rationals which are dense), then

$\emptyset = \cap \{D_q, O_n: q \in \mathbb{Q}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, which contradicts the Baireness of the reals, as all these sets are open and dense.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $U_n=O_n\setminus\{q_n\}$.

- Show that $U_n$ is still open.
- Show that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}U_n=\varnothing$.

Depending on the form in which you’ve proved the Baire category theorem, this may already be enough. If you really want to use the form in your question, let $F_n=\Bbb R\setminus U_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. These sets $F_n$ are already closed, so you know that there is some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\operatorname{int}F_n\ne\varnothing$. But $\operatorname{int}F_n=\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}U_n=\ldots\;?$